# Flutter: How do I create a widget that contains distinct instances of a list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, list, mobile

I'll try my best to explain my problem, but the phrasing is difficult as you can tell from the title. I have a list, todayExercises, that is edited by each instance of the widget DayExercisePage, rather than the widget editing each instance of the list.

```
class _DayExercisePageState extends State<DayExercisePage> {
    List<Exercise> todaysExercises = [];

  //Saving chicanery

  // Load data from shared preferences
  Future<List<Exercise>> loadData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? myDataString = prefs.getString('todaysExercises');
    if (myDataString != null) {
      final List<dynamic> myDataJson = jsonDecode(myDataString);
      todaysExercises =
          myDataJson.map((dynamic item) => Exercise.fromMap(item)).toList();
    }
    return todaysExercises;
  }

  // Save Todays exercieses to shared preferences
  Future<void> saveData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<dynamic> myDataJson =
        todaysExercises.map((Exercise exercise) => exercise.toMap()).toList();
    final String myDataString = jsonEncode(myDataJson);
    await prefs.setString('todaysExercises', myDataString);
  }
```

Each tile in the following image has its own instance of DayExercisePage which it routes to when clicked.
[image]

However, each instance of DayExercisePage builds with the same todaysExercises list.

[image]

How do I make the todayExercises list unique to each DayExercisePage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save and load different instances. An each day page you are overwriting the same list. But you should save a new instance, depending on the day. Just pass your day identifier (number, id, name, etc.) to you shared preferences key.

```dart
await prefs.setString('todaysExercises $dayNumber', myDataString);
```

And when you are getting your list too:

```dart
final String? myDataString = prefs.getString('todaysExercises $dayNumber');
```